# I cannot not go to second window in appcelerator

Tags: window, titanium, appcelerator

I am new in Titanium Studio. I am trying to do that when user clicks the any button in window1, it goes the second window. I mean I cannot connect to button1 and button2 in order to pass through the second window.

Here is the my sample code. Can anyone help me please?

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');


var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
layout : 'vertical',
title : 'Welcome to BMI'
});


var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton(
{
title:'Standart',
top : 300,
height: 20,
width: 100
});
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    win1.close();
    win2.open();
});


var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton(
{
title:'Metric',
top : 350,
height: 20,
width: 100
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    win1.close();
    win2.open();
});

win1.add(button1);
win1.add(button2);
win1.open();

var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  layout: 'vertical',
  title: 'BMI'
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color: '#900',
  font: { fontSize:48 },
  shadowColor: '#aaa',
  shadowOffset: {x:5, y:5},
  text: 'Body Mass Index',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  top: 30,
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color:'blue',
  text: 'Welcome to BMI',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
  top: 30,
  width: 300, height: 200
});


win2.add(label1);
win2.add(label2);
```

Comment: Hi, I've tested your code with SDK 3.1.3GA on Android and it works for me. I see win1(black background) with button1 and button2 on it, then I press a button and it opens win2(white background). What's wrong? Do you expect another behaviour?

Comment: Yeah I handled the issue. Here is the problem,

win1.add(button1);
win1.add(button2);
win1.open();

I delete the win1.open() it started work well. When I put the win1.open() over there, I think compiler see the code and starts run the first windows. I donot need that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not face problem to execute this code but i think you need to do some modification in your code.

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

function openNewWin(){
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  layout: 'vertical',
  title: 'BMI'
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color: '#900',
  font: { fontSize:48 },
  shadowColor: '#aaa',
  shadowOffset: {x:5, y:5},
  text: 'Body Mass Index',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  top: 30,
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color:'blue',
  text: 'Welcome to BMI',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
  top: 30,
  width: 300, height: 200
});


win2.add(label1);
win2.add(label2);
win2.open({
    modal : true
});
}

var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
layout : 'vertical',
title : 'Welcome to BMI'
});


var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton(
{
title:'Standart',
top : 300,
height: 20,
width: 100
});
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    win1.close();
    openNewWin();
});


var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton(
{
title:'Metric',
top : 350,
height: 20,
width: 100
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    win1.close();
    openNewWin();
});

win1.add(button1);
win1.add(button2);
win1.open({
    modal : true
});
```

Comment: I handled the issue. Thanks for helping

Comment: I read your comment and amazed that how its possible to not use open method and still it opens window...?

Comment: Mitul Bhalia, I think you misunderstood my comment, actually released that I didn't remark the comment well. So I didnot delete the open method, I just moved itdifferent line. For the sake of clarity, I cannot write my code again that is modificated.